# selenium, job scrapping, linkedIn, Show results button

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I wrote a code to log in to the linkedIn and search a word. Then, it should filter the results, I selected posts, and selected Date posted, and selected past 24 hours, but after it, I could not click the "Show results" button to continue as it is in different html tag or something, I do not know please give a code to click that button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
# driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/login")
username = driver.find_element(By.ID, "username")
password = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
username.send_keys(<username>)
password.send_keys(<password>)
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Wait for the home page to load
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "search-global-typeahead__input"))
)

# Search for job postings with a certain keyword posted in the last 24 hours
search_box = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "search-global-typeahead__input")
search_box.send_keys("freelance")
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(10)

# Find the "Posts" filter option and click on it
posts_filter = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Posts']")
posts_filter.click()
time.sleep(10)

# sort_by_button=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Sort by']")
# sort_by_button.click()
# time.sleep(10)

# Latest_option=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Latest']")
# Latest_option.click()
# time.sleep(5)

date_posted_button=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Date posted']")
date_posted_button.click()
time.sleep(5)

# Wait for the "Past 24 hours" option to be clickable and click on it
past_24_hours_option=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Past 24 hours']")
past_24_hours_option.click()
time.sleep(5)

show_results_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-control-name='filter_show_results'] span.artdeco-button__text")
show_results_button.click()
```

```
error 
 ElementNotInteractableException           Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2504\2775449269.py in <module>
     29 
     30 show_results_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-control-name='filter_show_results'] span.artdeco-button__text")
---> 31 show_results_button.click()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in click(self)
     92     def click(self) -> None:
     93         """Clicks the element."""
---> 94         self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
     95 
     96     def submit(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    401             params = {}
    402         params["id"] = self._id
--> 403         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    404 
    405     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None) -> WebElement:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    438         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    439         if response:
--> 440             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    441             response["value"] = self._unwrap_value(response.get("value", None))
    442             return response

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    243                 alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    244             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 245         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

I need to change this 2 lines of code, please help me, thanks in advance.

```
show_results_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-control-name='filter_show_results'] span.artdeco-button__text")
show_results_button.click()
```

the button image that I could not click with code is here.
[Show results should be clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efIka.png)